# Seven circles but only one is changing colour, why?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I have an assignment to create seven circles which should change colour on a mouse click. The first circle is changing colour but the other six just remain red, despite the fact I am calling the same method on a click?? I cannot use JQuery in my answer, only javascritpt. Any help is much appreciated!

My instinct was to try and create a for loop but this is not working for me..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Circles of rainbow colours</title>
     
    
     
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <h2> Rainbow Colours</h2>
     <svg height="1000" width="500"> 
     <circle  id="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="50" r="40" 
    style="fill:red;"/>
     <circle  id ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="150" r="40" 
    style="fill:red;"/>
     <circle  id ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="250" r="40"  
    style="fill:red;"/>
     <circle  id ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="350" r="40" 
    style="fill:red;"/>
     <circle  id ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="450" r="40" 
    style="fill:red;"/>
     <circle  id ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="550" r="40" 
    style="fill:red;"/>
     <circle  id ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="650" r="40" 
    style="fill:red;"/>
     </circle>
     
     </svg>
    
    
    <script>
     
       var circle = document.getElementById("circle1");
    
       
     colors = ['orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo','violet'];
     
     circle.onclick = function () 
     
     
     {
      color = colors.shift();
      colors.push(color);
     
      circle.style.fill = color;
     }
     
     
     </script>
    
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: You should never use the same ID across multiple elements. `getElementById` will only ever return at most 1 element. As such it will only ever work on the first circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements in HTML must have a unique `id` attribute, otherwise, your HTML is considered invalid.

Instead, you should use a `class`, this way you can iterate through your selected elements (here I have used `.forEach`), and apply the `click` handler to each.

**Note:** Now that you're using a class, you need to use `getElementsByClassName()` which will give you a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) of matching elements.

See working example below:

```js
const circles = [...document.getElementsByClassName("circle1")], // use spread syntax to convert collection to array
colors = ['orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];

circles.forEach(circle => {
  circle.onclick = function() {
    color = colors.shift();
    colors.push(color);
    circle.style.fill = color;
  }
});
```

```html
<h2> Rainbow Colours</h2>
<svg height="1000" width="500"> 
    <circle  class="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="50" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  class ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="150" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  class ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="250" r="40"  
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  class="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="350" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  class="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="450" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  class ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="550" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  class="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="650" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. I used this in the end. It really helped. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

An id (identifier) needs to be unique, document.getElementById() always catches the first one only.

Use a class and loop

Answer (score 0):

In the onclick function pass the element itself using this keyword. **It works in this case but remember it is wrong to give same id to more than 1 element. It should be unique.**

```js
var circle = document.getElementById("circle1");


colors = ['orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];
function a(e)

{
  color = colors.shift();
  colors.push(color);

  e.style.fill = color;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <h2> Rainbow Colours</h2>
  <svg height="1000" width="500"> 
    <circle  id="circle1" onclick="a(this)"  cx="50" cy="50" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  id ="circle1" onclick="a(this)"  cx="50" cy="150" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  id ="circle1" onclick="a(this)"  cx="50" cy="250" r="40"  
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  id ="circle1" onclick="a(this)"  cx="50" cy="350" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  id ="circle1" onclick="a(this)"  cx="50" cy="450" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  id ="circle1" onclick="a(this)"  cx="50" cy="550" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  id ="circle1" onclick="a(this)"  cx="50" cy="650" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`querySelectorAll('circle')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to query all circles by their element name.

Also do not use the same id on all circles, **element ids must be unique**.

You can then use a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) to iterate on your circles and attach your click handler with [`circle.addEventListener('click', handler)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Using this technique, you don't need ids or classes to refer to your circles, and you can also remove your onclick handler on each circle in your HTML:

```
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" style="fill:red;"/>
```

Here is an example:

```js
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('circle');

const colors = ['orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo','violet'];

circles.forEach(circle => {
  circle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    color = colors.shift();
    colors.push(color);
    circle.style.fill = color;
  });
});
```

```html
<svg height="1000" width="500"> 
  <circle cx="50" cy="50"  r="40" style="fill:red;"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="150" r="40" style="fill:red;"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="250" r="40" style="fill:red;"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="350" r="40" style="fill:red;"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="450" r="40" style="fill:red;"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="550" r="40" style="fill:red;"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="650" r="40" style="fill:red;"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple element with same id. Instead of id use class and add event listener to it

```js
var circle = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
let colors = ['orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];

[...circle].forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    item.style.fill = colors[index]
  })
})
```

```html
<h2> Rainbow Colours</h2>
<svg height="1000" width="500"> 
    <circle  id="circle1" class ="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  id ="circle1" class ="circle"cx="50" cy="150" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  id ="circle1" class ="circle"  cx="50" cy="250" r="40"  
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  id ="circle1" class ="circle"  cx="50" cy="350" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  id ="circle1" class ="circle"  cx="50" cy="450" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  id ="circle1" class ="circle"  cx="50" cy="550" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  id ="circle1" class ="circle"  cx="50" cy="650" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: why is `[...circle]` necessary? Can't you just do `circle.forEach` ?

Comment: @TKoL I dont think so

Comment: Works in jsfiddle.

Comment: Apparently some older browsers don't support `nodeList.forEach`, BUT those browsers also will not support `[...circle]` syntax either. I don't think there are any browsers where using the spread operator here does anything of value.

Comment: `circle` is a collection and `forEach` is an array method. So it will not work. Check the console of this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/phx73mdf/

Comment: That's so weird. When you use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassName`, `forEach` works. Why would they make these two interfaces so drastically different?

Answer (score 0):

id attributes are for referencing single Items, while Class attributes are for referencing group of items..

so changing ID to Class would look like this.. -

```
<svg height="1000" width="500"> 
    <circle  class="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="50" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  class ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="150" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  class ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="250" r="40"  
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  class ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="350" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  class ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="450" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  class ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="550" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  class ="circle1" onclick="function()"  cx="50" cy="650" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    </circle>

    </svg>
```

and then you get the group of items by their class name using this..

```
var circle = document.getElementsByClassName("circle1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on class instead of a fix id. Use below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Circles of rainbow colours</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2> Rainbow Colours</h2>
    <svg height="1000" width="500"> 
    <circle  onclick="changecolor(this);"  cx="50" cy="50" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  onclick="changecolor(this);"  cx="50" cy="150" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  onclick="changecolor(this);"  cx="50" cy="250" r="40"  
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  onclick="changecolor(this);"  cx="50" cy="350" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  onclick="changecolor(this);" cx="50" cy="450" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle  onclick="changecolor(this);" cx="50" cy="550" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    <circle onclick="changecolor(this);" cx="50" cy="650" r="40" 
style="fill:red;"/>
    </circle>

    </svg>


<script>

colors = ['orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo','violet'];
function changecolor(e) {
    color = colors.shift();
    colors.push(color);

    e.style.fill = color;
}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this `
let circles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('circle'));

circles.forEach((circle) =>{
circle.onclick = function ()            {       color = colors.shift();         colors.push(color);             circle.style.fill = color;  }
}
`

## cheers